# Laravel: Eager loading specific columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Why does

```
Order::with(['products'=>function($q){
    $q->select('name', 'price', 'quantity')->orderBy('name','asc');
  }])->paginate($length);
```

returns all orders with their respective product data, but

```
Order::with(['products'=>function($q){
    $q->select('name', 'price', 'quantity')->orderBy('name','asc');
  }])->select('pickup_date', 'pickup_time', 'remark')->paginate($length);
```

gives me all order data I want, but an empty products array?

I want to select some specific columns from the order table with some specific columns from the products table. How can I do this?

FYI:
Orders-products have a many-to-many relationship with models:
Order Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Product Model:

```
public function orders()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Order')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: your select method will be like this `select('products.id as product_id', 'pickup_date', 'pickup_time', 'remark')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select like this way :

```
Order::with(['products'=>function($q){
    $q->orderBy('name','asc');
  }])->select('products.name as name','products.price as price','products.quantity as quantity','orders.pickup_date as pickup_date', 'orders.pickup_time as pickup_time', 'orders.remark as remark')->paginate($length);
```

Or without sub query :

```
Order::with('products')
   ->select('products.name as name','products.price as price','products.quantity as quantity','orders.pickup_date as pickup_date', 'orders.pickup_time as pickup_time', 'orders.remark as remark')
   ->orderBy('name','asc');
   ->paginate($length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one thing,you should add product id in outer select.

```
Order::with(['products'=>function($q){
    $q->select('name', 'price', 'quantity')->orderBy('name','asc');
  }])->select('product_id','pickup_date', 'pickup_time', 'remark')->paginate($length);
```

I hope it would be helpful

Comment: That way I get an exception: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id'. The foreign key in the pivot table is 'product_id' though

Comment: What do you mean? It's a many-to-many relationship. The foreign keys in the pivot are order_id and product_id, pointing to orders.id and products.id respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Order::query()
    ->select(['pickup_date', 'pickup_time', 'remark'])
    ->with(['products:name,price,quantity'])
    ->paginate($length);
```